# Show that $A^{\dagger} A$ is strictly positive?

Tags: matrices

Show that $A^{\dagger} A$ is positive definite if $\det(A)$ is not equal to zero. I do not know how to make use of $\det(A)$ is not equal to zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that if A is an invertible matrix, then A\*A is Hermitian and positive definite.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296525/prove-that-if-a-is-an-invertible-matrix-then-aa-is-hermitian-and-positive-defi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\det(A)$ is non-zero, then $A$ is invertible.  In particular: in such a situation, we have
$$
\|Ax\| = 0 \iff x = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

$A^\dagger A$ is Hermitian, thus can be diagonalized with real eigenvalues. The fact that $\det(A)\neq 0$ means that none of the eigenvalues are zero. This should be sufficient to prove that $A^\dagger A$ is positive definite.